# 'Activities overview' is not working properly; it cuts out windows

Tags: 20.04, activities-overview

I installed some updates to Ubuntu 20.04 and the 'Activities overview' stopped working fine. This only shows the search engine and cuts the screens that are open.

In this image you can see the problem:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found that it was caused by the "Workspaces to Dock" extension. Disabling this extension fixed the issue. Unfortunately it is no longer maintained.